# How to mirror text position?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to lay some text out on left and right that have a mirroring position as below.

[image]

What's happening here is that the last row in the right column ("Some more text") is the widest so it pushes the two rows above further to the right. For the sake of symmetry, the left column is pushed further to the left. The text values are supposed to be dynamic. Does anyone know how the layouts should be designed?

Here's my code (sadly, it doesn't even align to the right!):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/description_30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">        
            <TextView android:id="@+id/title_30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="30 DAYS"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/num_ds_30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_30"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/num_bs_30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                android:layout_below="@id/num_ds_30"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/description_today"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description_30">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/title_today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="TODAY"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/num_ds_today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_today"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/num_bs_today"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"          
            android:layout_below="@id/num_ds_today"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @TomerMor Sure. I've done that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like that by nesting `LinearLayout`s. The outer `LinearLayout` would have an `orientation=horizontal`, and the two inner `LinearLayout` an orientation of `vertical` with each having a `layout_weight=1` and the second (right) `LinearLayout` would also have `gravity="right"`.

The code would be something like this.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                  ... />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="right">

                <TextView
                      ... />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With `gravity=right` at the `LinearLayout` level leaves no right margin though, i.e. it takes all 3 TextViews to the rightmost of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @Kate You can set the margin in the outermost `LinearLayout` so it's symmetrical for both children layouts, with `layout_marginRight=".."` and `layout_marginLeft="..."`.

Comment: Sure. However, the text values are dynamic so the margin sizes depend on the widest TextView. For instance, if 'Some more text' was just 'More text', the margins would widen and get closer to the centre.

Comment: @Kate Now I understand. Well, then you can add another `LinearLayout` encapsulating the second `LinearLayout`. I will update the code. Basically the second layout has `layout_weight="1"` and the third layout (innermost right), has `wrap_content` as width /height and `gravity="right"`, such that it will position the views as you said.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks!

Comment: Should the `layout_width` of the `LinearLayout`s in the second layer be `0dp` rather than `wrap_content` since `layout_weight` is used?

Comment: @Kate Yes, better use 0dp, otherwise it behaves a bit differently it seems. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a RelativeLayout and aligning the TextViews to the left/right is a good approach. Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1_Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2_Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Text1_Left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text3_Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Text2_Left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1_Right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Text1_Left"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2_Right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Text1_Right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Text2_Left"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text3_Right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Text2_Right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Text1_Left"
        android:gravity="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```